# apache2 debian mod folder location

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, php

I have apache folder on Debian with configuration (apache2.conf file, not httpd.conf) in /etc/apache2. On another configuration I hasn't this folder, but it was located in /usr/local/apache2/bin. Config file was httpd.conf.
I need location of folders bin, and especially apxs.
Thank you very much.

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Server built:   Jan 10 2015 15:51:04
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:30
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.4.1
Compiled using: APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.4.1
Architecture:   32-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/var/run/apache2/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

The point is, that I want install PHP from source, and don't know apxs folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you are missing some files, you need to make sure you have the module that provides it installed in your system. Under Ubuntu, if you type `apxs` on a terminal, it will provide you with suggestions.

Different paths are possible for apache installation. They may differ by Linux distribution you are using. For example, you can find configuration under `/etc/apache2` in Ubuntu and binary under `/usr/sbin/apache2`. However, config files are located under `/etc/httpd` in CentOS and binary under `/usr/sbin/httpd`.

The path `/usr/local/apache2/bin` seems to be installation from source (not using package management like `apt-get` or `yum`) unless this is the default path for another distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Command apxs is not found. There are few apache related executables. The point is, that I want install PHP from source, and don't know apxs folder. Yes,  /usr/local/apache2/bin path was for apache compiled from source.

Answer (score 1):

As you're planning to build PHP from source and have it interface with your Apache, you will need the `apache2-dev` package. Once you install it, you'll find `apxs` in `/usr/bin`.

In Debian/Ubuntu, the `apxs` binary is in the `apache2-dev` package, since if you only use pre-built binary packages, you won't ever need `apxs`. And if you *do* need `apxs`, you will most likely also need the Apache `*.h` files... which are also in the `apache2-dev` package.